# How to reference an array of EditText created in main.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, loops, android-edittext

My app is getting a little bloated, I would like to 'compress' some code by changing some of my variables into arrays and using some for loops to process my variables.
My first target is initializing my EditText boxes

My original code (working fine) included:

```
EditText miBox1, spBox1 ;   
EditText miBox2, spBox2 ;
```

...

```
miBox1 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.miBox1);
spBox1 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.spBox1);
miBox2 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.miBox2);
spBox2 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.spBox2);
```

I actually have twenty mi boxes and 20 sp boxes to setup
I am trying to create an array, and loop through them

In my main.xml I have renamed my EditText boxes to 
miBox[1] spBox[1], etc.

I'm declaring in my activity with:

```
EditText[] miBox = new EditText[20] ;    
EditText[] spBox = new EditText[20] ;
```

and putting this into a for loop

```
miBox[i] = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.miBox[i]);
spBox[i] = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.spBox[i]);
```

but Eclipse cannot resolve R.id.miBox[i]

How do I properly create an array of EditText in my xml so that
it is recognized?

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("miBox" + i,
    "id", getPackageName());
```

where i is your index

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(resId);
```

if you want to put it in an array, simply do this :

```
 miBox[i] = (EditText)findViewById(resId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  
So I am clear - do I still use an array? Is "miBox" + 1 referring to an element in an array, or my 'original' naming technique without array?

Comment: In response to your edit - 'if you want to put it in an array...'    Cool - I think that is exactly what I need. I will give it a try when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Reno - Works great. Reduced each of my activity file sizes by more than 50 percent - Thanks - GREAT answer  JD

Answer (score 3):

the problem here is you have wrongly modified a few things.

the code should be like:

```
EditText[] miBox = new EditText[20] ;    
EditText[] spBox = new EditText[20] ;
```

and putting this into a for loop

```
miBox[i] = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.miBox1);
spBox[i] = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.spBox1);
```

Here, the msitake is using `miBox[i]` since thats not the id you have used in your layout xml.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

In my revised code, I am trying to identify the resource in a loop.
I can't use (R.id.miBox1) in the loop as it refers only to Box1.

In my main.xml I have renamed my EditText boxes from miBox1, etc to miBox[1], miBox[2] etc.

Comment: hmm.. I see...in that case you can either try what Reno told you Or, if you go through your generated R file and see the values of the  `miBox` ..if they are serial you can use those values instead of `R.id.miBox[i]` .... e.g.  miBox[i]=(EditText) this.findViewById(i); //where i= the incremented variable in a for loop with an initial value of something like  0x7f050000